# Clear array an assign new elements

Tags: arrays, performance, actionscript-3, memory-leaks

I have the following code:

```
if ((mySo.data.currentIds != null ) &&
    (mySo.data.currentIds.length > 0))
    currentIds = mySo.data.currentIds.split(',');
```

Previously, `currentIds` was initialized with this code:

```
currentIds = new Array(-1, -1, -1);
```

I want to ask if this is the best way to replace elements with new ones in an array:

```
currentIds = mySo.data.currentIds.split(',');
```

I'm talking about memory leaks and performance. I don't know if previous instance of `currentIds' is cleared from memory or not.

Maybe, I can do this instead:

```
currentIds.splice(0, 3, mySo.data.currentIds.split(','));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any issues with this. Assuming your array only contains numbers and not references to objects...seems to me that you're just creating a new array.

Comment: And what's about with the previous array assigned to `currentIds`? Am I creating a memory leak?

Comment: @VansFannel, If you have lots of references to currentIds, you could be creating a memory leak. Though likely it's ok. However, your `splice` isn't doing what you think it's doing. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If the previous array is not referenced anywhere else then it will be marked for garbage collection.  That doesn't mean that it will be destroyed immediately, but that Flash can and will destroy it when it needs to.

Answer (score 2):

***Your splice syntax is bad.***

With the splice, what you are doing is putting `mySo.data.currentIds.split(',')` into the first index of `currentIds`:

```
var currentIds:Array = [-1, -1, -1];
currentIds.splice(0, 3, [1,2,3]);
//The entire array is in index 0:
trace(currentIds.length); //1
trace(currentIds[0]);     //1,2,3
```

---

However, depending on what you intend, a splice type of thing could be better. For example, if you reference the currentIds with another variable somewhere else, `new Array`. That reference will continue to point to the old array.

eg.

```
var currentIds:Array = [-1, -1, -1];
var currentIdsReference:Array = currentIds;
currentIds = [1,2,3];
trace(currentIdsReference); //-1,-1,-1
```

vs

```
var currentIds:Array = [-1, -1, -1];
var currentIdsReference:Array = currentIds;
currentIds.length = 0;
currentIds.push.apply(null, [1,2,3]);
trace(currentIdsReference); //1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if we knew what you're trying to accomplish; specifically if you're trying to create arrays within arrays (I don't think so, but it's hard to tell without any idea of what each piece is for).

Also, you didn't let us know what variable types you're working with. `.split()` is a `String` function, not an `Array` function.

As for garbage collection, if you replace the existing array with a new one (via whatever method) then the old array should be collected and disposed of eventually -- as long as you don't have any other references to it.

Finally, I'd point out that you might have an encapsulation issue -- not strictly a code error, but possibly indicating poor design. You show that you're accessing `mySo.data.currentIds`. What is `mySo` and `data`? And why are you reaching down into them? That's potentially adding a lot of coupling. You might want to refactor to do something like: `mySo.resetIds();` instead.